# Implementing my own utility functions in Lithium?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, web, lithium

I am a newbie to Lithium PHP and know the basics of Lithium. I want to implement my own `Utility` functions. I have created the `utilities` folder parallel to `app\controllers`. This is how my class looks like:

```
<?php

namespace app\utilities;

class UtilityFunctions {
    protected $_items = array(
            'a' => 'Apple',
            'b' => 'Ball',
            'c' => 'Cat'
        );

    //I get _items as undefined here, blame my poor OOP skills.
    public function getItem(alphabet) {
        return $this->_items[alphabet];
    }
}

?>
```

I use it in my controller as:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use \app\utilities\UtilityFunctions;

class MyController extends \lithium\action\Controller {
    public function index() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        $item = UtilityFunctions::getItem($args[0]);

        return compact('item');
    }
}

?>
```

Is this the right way to do it? Does my utility class need to extend something? Or does Lithium provide some other way to achieve this?

Moreover, I am not able to access the protected variable `$_items` in my `getItems` method. I had the same thing implemented in my controller and it worked fine then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fine way to do it. There are two core Lithium classes that you could extend from: [\lithium\core\Object](http://li3.me/docs/lithium/core/Object) and [\lithium\core\StaticObject](http://li3.me/docs/lithium/core/StaticObject)

I think that is not necessary for your use case.

The reason you cannot access the protected variable is because you are invoking the method statically. You should probably rewrite your class to use static variables and methods. Also, I assume it's just a typo creating an example for StackOverflow, but you forgot the `$` for the `alphabet` var in the `getItem` method.

```
<?php

namespace app\utilities;

class UtilityFunctions {
    protected static $_items = array(
        'a' => 'Apple',
        'b' => 'Ball',
        'c' => 'Cat'
    );

    public static function getItem($alphabet) {
        return static::_items[$alphabet];
    }
}

?>
```

The other option is to not change the UtilityFunctions class, but instead instantiate the class in the controller:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use app\utilities\UtilityFunctions;

class MyController extends \lithium\action\Controller {
    public function index() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        $utilities = new UtilityFunctions();
        $item = $utilities->getItem($args[0]);

        return compact('item');
    }
}

?>
```

For a simple case like this where the class does not need to hold any state, I would recommend the static methods. Take a look at the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) for a little more info on the static keyword.

Another minor note, you do not need the leading backslash in your `use` statement.

Comment: Just to add to what rmarscher said, @Rutwick Gangurde - you should consider extending from StaticObject and Object as rmarscher pointed out. You can do some pretty cool things with filters in li3 (Google that). Also, consider using PHP Traits for your use case.

Comment: Thanks rmarscher and @housni. It was a typo, been doing a lot of JavaScript these days hence forgot the $ sign. I followed the second approach by instantiating the class. I will read more upon the static keyword.